# Separate Multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

I have two Table 'movies' and movie_embeds

In Movies

id            title       description
1         Movie1       
Desc1
2         Movie2         
Desc2
3         Movie3         
Desc3

In movie_embeds

id     movie_id     link
1         1             
link1
2         1             
link2
3         1             
link3
4         2             
link4
5         2             
link5
6         3             
link6

**code:**

```php
    $sql = "SELECT *
    FROM movies, movie_embeds
    WHERE movies.id = movie_embeds.movie_id
     GROUP BY movies.title "; 

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<p>';
        echo  $row['title'];

    echo '<p>';
        echo $row['link'];

    echo '<p>';
        echo $row['meta'];

    echo '<p>';

    }
```

**Result:**

```php
Movie1
link1
Desc1

movie2
link4
Desc2

movie3
link6
Desc3
```

Problem is How can i have link2 and link3 in first and other results?

If i remove GROUP BY movies.title movie title and all duplicated 3 times. Help?

I need Result like this

**I need Result Like this:**

```php
Movie1
link1
link2
link3
Desc1

movie2
link4
link5
Desc2

movie3
link6
Desc3
```

I attached sql and php code
[Test Php file](http://bomaza.com/test.txt)
[Test sql](http://bomaza.com/test.sql)

Comment: Please, refrain from this usage of `GROUP BY`. The only columns you should be selecting from this statement are those in your `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What you are showing cannot be a true representation of what you are running. For a start there is no column "meta" in your tables or your query, yet you are apparently outputting such a column. By the way, you are not closing your paragraph tags. Don't use implicit comma joins, use JOIN keywords. Finally the query would not give the  output you suggest. It would include all the links. Please show us what you REALLY have, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: IF i remove group by, i have duplicate group title. If count 3 link in duplicate also 3 same title with three links.

Comment: rename the php file as a .txt one or we cannot download it

Comment: Pls check i renamed as text.. Thank you

Comment: Can I suggest that you completely re-write this question and this time tell the truth about what you have and give a sensible question so that we know what you are attempting. I have run he code that you supplied in the files and it doesn't at all resemble the "question" and the question itself is not even true within itself. I will gladly help you but you have to make an effort to make yourself understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better to do it like this:

```
  SELECT m.*,me.*
    FROM movies m
    JOIN movie_embeds me ON (me.movie_id=m.id)
    GROUP BY m.title;
```

Edit:
you could try removing the group by and adding a distinct, but i think it maybe your printer code that is at fault. have you tried running the query from a third party client?

Comment: This query also giving same result. How can i get link2 and link3 in first title??

Comment: Pls can u help about DISTINT.. Pls. i used echo $row['link']; but link have one or more result i need like this  Movie1
link1
link2
link3
Desc1

Comment: Sir Pls cheeck i attached php and mytest sql. Pls help this is urgent one... check first movie name duplicated 3 times..becous it have 3 links all other have only one link